# How to fix other controllers url in codeigniter3

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, codeigniter-3

I'm setting my new web site by using the frimework codeignter3 i already i have the default controller named by "home" and its working great but when i tried to creat new controller "activecode" i can't access to the view.

This website running at : Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2 and php using codeigniter 3

My controller : Codeactive.php

```php
<?php
class Codeactive extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();

       $this->load->database();
       $this->load->helper('url');
         }
  public function index() {
   if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/ca.php')) {
      //Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
     show_404();
    }       
    $data['title'] = ucfirst('Codeactive'); 
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/ca', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
  }
}
```

My config :

```php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://revendeur.pro/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My route.php :

```php
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['codeactive/list'] = 'ca/list';
```

my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

i tried all soulutions in google and Nothing changed.

Comment: are you sure you have enabled `mod_rewrite` on the server?

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to access? codeactive/list doesn't have a function in the controller - you would need to rename index() to list()